# Insert Image Into MySQL Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a table called Images with ID (A_I) and Image (LONGBLOB) columns. I have seen other answers but it does not work for me. I should mention I'm using XAMPP. When I use the full PC file path it escapes characters because it uses '\'. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
<?PHP
$A = "localhost"; // Server Name
$B = "root";      // MySQL Username
$C = "";          // MySQL Password
$D = "sql";       // Database

$CONNECT = new mysqli($A, $B, $C, $D);

if ($CONNECT->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed");
}

echo "Connected";

$SQL = "INSERT INTO Images (ID, Image) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE('1.jpg'))";

if (mysqli_query($CONNECT, $SQL)) {
    echo "Image Sent";
} else {
    echo "Error Sending Image";
}
?>
```

Comment: You do need to use the full path. How are you entering the file name when it escapes the slashes?

Comment: The full path looks like this and in my editors it changes the colour of the '\' and the character after it. $SQL = "INSERT INTO Images (ID, Image) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\1.jpg'))";

Comment: Ignore the editor, or change the quotes around. Or better yet, use prepared statements and bind_param, which will eliminate any quoting/escaping issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape \ char by writing \ like this :

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Images (ID, Image) VALUES (1,LOAD_FILE('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1.jpg'))";
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I tried with another image also, doesn't work. I also created a new table based off a tutorial to the exact detail and it doesn't work.